# MediaStreamTrack.id change when using addTracks()

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I'm using MediaStream API in a web app which allow multiple user to make à conf call based on webrtc.
When I use MediaStream.addTracks() the id of my track (MediaStreamTrack) change.

Here is a concrete example :

```js
getUserMedia.call(navigator, {audio:true,video:false}, function(stream) {
    console.log(stream.getAudioTracks());                //(1)
    rtc.streams[0].addTrack(stream.getAudioTracks()[0]); //rtc object managed by webrtc.io
    console.log(rtc.streams[0].getAudioTracks());        //(2)
}, function() {
    console.log("Could not connect stream.");
    onFail();
});
```

**(1)** : At this point my audio track is

```
enabled: true
id: "0eKd3T3arsIgrnLsIplvfA69feDzxvwEnu8ga0"
kind: "audio"
label: "0eKd3T3arsIgrnLsIplvfA69feDzxvwEnu8ga0"
onended: null
onmute: null
onunmute: null
readyState: "live"
```

**(2)** : At this point my audio track is

```
enabled: true
id: "bd3ba276-8804-4c6e-8dd7-f1bd316150e8"
kind: "audio"
label: "0eKd3T3arsIgrnLsIplvfA69feDzxvwEnu8ga0"
onended: null
onmute: null
onunmute: null
readyState: "live"
```

As you can see the `id` has changed. Is this the normal behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. The API description on [webrtc.com](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/api-description#TOC-PeerConnection%3a%3aAddStream) shows that the mediastream parameter for the *addStream* function is only a constant reference. So the id shouldn't change.

Comment: Yes I know it shouldn't change, but it does, this is why I'm asking. And this is not _addStream_ but _addTracks_

Answer (score 0):

A new track added to stream when you are calling `addTrack` function. For example, if you had two tracks on a stream (a video track and a audio track), after calling `addTrack` function you have 3 tracks and any track replaced by new one. So you are getting the latest track properties that are different from previous.